# Creating a column based upon a list and column in Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark DataFrame, say df1, with multiple columns.

I also have a list, say, `l = ['a','b','c','d']` and these values are the subset of the values present in one of the columns in the DataFrame.

Now, I would like to do something like this:

```
df2 = df1.withColumn('new_column', expr("case when col_1 in l then 'yes' else 'no' end"))
```

But this is throwing the following error:

> failure: "(" expected but identifier l found.

Any idea how to resolve this error or any better way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with the `isin` function of the `Column` object:

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)], ('col1', 'col2'))
l = ['a', 'b']

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df2 = df1.withColumn('new_column', when(col('col1').isin(l), 'yes').otherwise('no'))

df2.show()

+----+----+----------+
|col1|col2|new_column|
+----+----+----------+
|   a|   1|       yes|
|   b|   2|       yes|
|   c|   3|        no|
+----+----+----------+
```

Note: For Spark < 1.5, use `inSet` instead of `isin`.

Reference: `pyspark.sql.Column` [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column)